# The elbow worked through the sleeve

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean "The elbow worked through the sleeve"?

and what is the synonym of the verb "worked" in the sentence?

Comment: Please provide full context.

Comment: **To work** has quite a long entry in the full OED. The cited usage here is probably 29a: *To **form** (a hole, groove, etc.) by constant friction or pressure; = **wear***.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the sleeve was worn out, and the elbow was visible through it.

Comment: I can understand it now, but one thing that I can't understand is that the verb "work" is used to express doing works. Can you explain the meaning of "work" to me?

Comment: @FumbleFingers gave you the best dictionary meaning.

Comment: "Worked", in this context, means that repeated action over time (ie, the "wearing away" of the cloth) caused the elbow to show through.

Comment: (You may also occasionally see "worried" used, with similar meaning.  Eg, "The elbow had worried a hole in the sleeve.")

Comment: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/work_1, see 12, 13, __14__